# How to add working days to a date in PLSQL?

Tags: plsql

I have to add Working Days, to find out Ship_Date, for an Order, depending upon Order_Date and Delivery_Type (Like Standard Delivery, Premium Delivery etc).

So the query should look like

```
SELECT Order_Id, Delivery_Type, Order_Date, Ship_Date FROM Order_Info
```

I found SQL for this problem but couldn't understand it and neither and could not refactor it for my needs. 
The query is as below

```
SELECT max(DATE_FIELD_TWO) AS DATE_FIELD_TWO
FROM (
         SELECT Date '2018-08-30' + CAST(
                 CASE
                     WHEN TO_CHAR(Date '2018-08-30' + Level, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') In
                          ('6', '7') Then 0

                     ELSE Level
                     END AS INT)                       AS DATE_FIELD_TWO,
                SUM(CAST(CASE
                             WHEN TO_CHAR(Date '2018-08-30' + Level, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') In ('6', '7')
                                 THEN 0
                             ELSE 1
                    End As Int)) OVER (Order By Level) AS NEXT_DAY
         FROM DUAL Connect By Level <= 20 * 1.5)

WHERE NEXT_DAY = 20;
```

Comment: Hi Vimal, welcome to SO. Please see  the help section [ask]. Using that as a template for your question gives you a much better chance of getting a satisfactory answer.  Please expand of the problem your trying to solve as requirements statements (not sql). In particular how are your delivery type and working days determined and are they related? If so how? Also provide sample data and the results of that data.

Comment: BTW: It appears the query you posted determines the date of Thur in 4 weeks given the specified date (at least thru Jan 2019).  Run the query repeatedly after changing the date to the result given by the prior run.